# /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file in aws lambda layer stack: Runtime.ImportModuleError

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-lambda-layers, python-3.11

I'm facing an issue with my AWS Lambda Layer Stack using **AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model**). I am encountering a `Runtime.ImportModuleError` with the following error message:

```
Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'signin': /opt/python/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_rust.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

This error is occurring within my AWS Lambda Layer stack. **This problem occurred when I migrated the runtime from 3.8 to 3.11.** Here's my `buildspec.yaml` file for reference:

```yaml
version: 0.2
# Buildspec Reference Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

# ... (Environment Variables and Phases) ...

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.11
    commands:
      # ... (Install phase commands) ...

  pre_build:
    commands:
      # ... (Pre-Build phase commands) ...
      - cd lambda_layers/global_utils/python
      - pip install -r requirements.txt -t .
      - cd ../../
      - cd ./node
      - npm install
      - mkdir -p ./nodejs
      - mv ./node_modules ./nodejs
      - cd ../../
      - ls

  build:
    commands:
      # ... (Build phase commands) ...
      - echo "Starting SAM packaging `date` in `pwd`"
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket $BUILD_OUTPUT_BUCKET --output-template-file package.yaml

  post_build:
    commands:
      # ... (Post-Build phase commands) ...
      - echo "SAM packaging completed on `date`"

# ... (Artifacts and Cache) ...
```

I suspect that the error might be related to the some issue with the Python runtime environment in AWS Lambda. Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I've tried different configurations, including changing --platform or `--only-binary=:all:` flag for the `pip install` command, but the issue persists.
I tried changing the lambda architecture ARM from x86.Problem will may be resolved if I remigrate to python 3.8 but I want to sort it out and switch to 3.11.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems to yours. Did you build your layers from the resource pulled from somewhere like git repository? I pushed my packages to the github with ignoring `.so` file setting in .gitingore, which caused _rust.abi3.so got lost. And then when my teammate pulled the resource from github and built layers,and deploy it to the aws, the similar error occured.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).